# Kept getting error (missing credentials) to connect Power BI Service to Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, powerbi, databricks, azure-databricks, connectivity

I have some issues with the connectivity from Databricks to Power BI service. After I have published my app to Power BI service, I would like to schedule a refresh with the data. However I found that an error pop up (missing credentials) in Power BI Service. The connection with Azure Databricks was lost in Power BI service.

When I tried to edit the credentials to reconnect with it, I kept getting the error:

```
"Failed to update data source credentials: [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (14) Unexpected response from server during a HTTP connection: Unauthorized/Forbidden error response returned, but no token expired message received.".
```

There are three options for me to connect: Basic, Key and OAuth2. I tried with OAuth2 by signing in my account and it didn't work. It doesn't happen in Power BI Desktop where I obtained my credential with Azure Active Directory (the same account).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow below steps:**

**Step 1:**

Go to data bricks cluster -> configuration ->JDBC/ODBC  then, Copy `Service Hostname` and `HTTP Path`.

[image: Ref1]

**Step 2:**

In my scenario I am using access token as authenticator .You can use Username/Password or Azure Active Directory.

For using Access Token Go to settings -> User settings -> Generate new access token.

[image: Ref2]

**Step 3:**

Go to Power Bi -> Get data -> Azure  -> Azure Databricks -> connect

[image]

**Step 4:**

Past the `Service Hostname` and  `HTTP Path` as you copied   in the Step1.

[image]

**Step 5:**

Past the token value as you Generated in the step 2.

[image]

You should able to see all the tables in the Databricks cluster and in the power bi navigator.

[image]